# Is there any performance difference between calling a local variable and calling an object's instance variable?

Tags: python, optimization, compiler-construction

Here's the code I have:

```
        elif line.mesg.startswith('^^'):
            recog, score = pull_recog(line)
            line.recog = recog
            line.score = score

            print recog + ' '*(20-len(recog)) + '%2.2f'%score
```

This question really comes down to how the compiler takes care of this:

Does the compiler optimize this code in some way that would make no difference between:

1. Calling the local variables `recog` and `score`
2. Calling the object's instance variables `line.score` and `line.recog`?

My initial instinct that using the local variables would be quicker, but I'm not getting good results from `timeit` so I can't really tell for sure.

This is within a for-loop, so optimization does actually matter in this case.

Comment: On timing it,  it is much quicker using local variable which your timings should have shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables are quicker. `line.score` is two operations: a local variable retrieval (for `line`) and an attribute lookup (for `score`). Whereas `recog` is only one operation, the local variable retrieval. One operation is faster than two, especially when one of the two is the same as the one.

You can see this very easily by inspecting the bytecode using the `dis` module.

```
from dis import dis

def myfunc(recog, line):
    recog
    line.score

dis(myfunc)
```

This part is the reference to `recog`:

```
 2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (recog)
```

And this is `line.score`:

```
 3           4 LOAD_FAST                1 (line)
             7 LOAD_ATTR                0 (score)
```

Q.E.D.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Hadn't heard of the dis module, I'll give it a shot on some other parts of code that I'm wondering about...

Comment: It's very useful for really getting into the depths of Python.